# Should there be tag [aviation-in-fiction]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

In [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com), there is tag [chemistry-in-fiction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry-in-fiction), arguably due to lots of questions on [Breaking Bad](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747). Given the recent question on the *Top Gun* dilogy, should there be tag [aviation-in-fiction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-in-fiction)?

For example, the search query `[f-14] -[aviation-in-fiction]` would allow one to filter the questions with the tag [f-14](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-14) but (hopefully) excluding the ones pertaining to the *Top Gun* dilogy.

Answer (score 3):

I would be very hesitant to add such a tag.

Being fiction, the risk of the question not being grounded in reality is high, and the answer could easily end up being an opinion fight.

If we decide to add it, I propose it is with the caveat that anything not based on physics is pointed out, and no attempt is made to describe "how it could have been done in reality".

Comment: If the question cannot be answered and devolves into an opinion fight, then I would claim that it is off-topic and should be closed.  Of course, not all opinions are equal.

Comment: There are already questions on aviation in movies, e.g., *Top Gun*, *Air Force One*, etc.  Creating the tag would allow one to have all such questions under the same tag, and one could then ignore such tag.

Comment: Personally I don't see the need to create such a tag for existing questions, and I am afraid of the effect it could have if created.

Comment: Nearly 10 months later, 14 questions are tagged.  Do you think their quality is unacceptably low?

Answer (score 2):

No, we should not as I believe that would be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/?_ga=2.99345625.630761987.1662363908-466983025.1661857200).

Looking at the tests for such

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Having a [aviation-in-fiction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-in-fiction) tag would not work on its own. It tells you nothing about the expertise needed to answer the question, nor the content of it in any meaningful way

> If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Would [aviation-in-fiction](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-in-fiction) mean something about a fictional aircraft, or a real aircraft from a film, or a book, or some wild out-there idea on the internet? It clearly means different things to different people.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138995/discussion-on-answer-by-jamiec-should-there-be-tag-aviation-in-fiction).

Comment: You encouraged me to create the tag and then [rejected](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62770) the edit that would create said tag.  Is this some sort of prank?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo to me, you should not remove a well-used tag to make space for your new pet project.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I agree wholey with Federico. Which is why I rejected it. Aerodynamics tells us a lot more about the content of that question than your aviation in fiction meta-tag

Comment: @Jamiec The OP assumed it had something to do with aerodynamics.  Was that the case?  If not, why preserve a wrong assumption?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I mean it _did_ have to do with aerodynamics, but that's beside the point. It didn't have to do with air to air combat -so  you could have removed aerial combat tag.

Comment: @Jamiec Frankly, I don't see what tactical maneuvers have to do with aerodynamics. I could have removed [aerial-combat], had I recalled whether it encompasses air-to-ground or not. Since you are a moderator, you can rectify my imperfect tagging.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You mean you didnt read every single tag usage guidelines??!? Didnt you [say that should be a ban-worthy offense](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61935904#61935904)?

Comment: @Jamiec Am I the OP? I didn't create the monster. I merely chopped one of its limbs off. What did you do to kill the monster?